# JQuery Mobile + PhoneGap for Android - Error loading index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, mobile, cordova

I am trying to get a basic **PhoneGap + JQuery Mobile** program running for **Android platform 2.2**, but I am getting an Application Error "The Connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)" in the Android Emulator when I try to run the application in Android Emulator platform 2.2 on **Windows XP**, with **Eclipse 3.7**.

The file loads if I remove all references and syntax of JQuery Mobile from the HTML file, so I am certain that my project is fine but there's something I am missing with initialization of JQuery Mobile. I am using **PhoneGap 0.9.6** with **JQuery Mobile version **1.0b1**** with **JQuery version 1.6.1** (I also tried with JQM Version 1.0a2 with JQuery 1.4.4 but with the same error).

If I remove all references to JQuery Mobile from my HTML file then I am able to load the program in the emulator without errors.

I looked at several examples on the web and tried them as they are, but all of them show the same error. My files are as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap With JQM</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.6.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>  
          <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="e">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>PhoneGap with JQM</h1> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>My Content</h1>  
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>My Footer</h1>  
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main.js file has only:

```
function init()
{   
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);             
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The index.html file is as below:

Comment: My problem got solved (thanks to Viras on **PhoneGap Google Groups**). The issue occurs as the Android emulator is REALLY slow
so a timeout occurs while loading the files because it reacts too slow.

Within your custom Activity file before calling super.loadUrl add the
following line:

super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);

Comment: Please answer your question or close it if your problem is solved, I just wasted 2 minutes of my life!

Answer (score 25):

The problem is likely due to the speed of the emulator so the network is too slow complete the communication in a timely fashion.

Set a 60 second timeout in PhoneGap by adding the following property  to `src/com/phonegap/xxx.java`:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

**References:**

[phonegap 0.9.3 onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/3336e5dfbb98120e/571aa73d49446092?lnk=gst&q=The+connection+to+the+server+was+unsuccessful#571aa73d49446092)

[http://The%20connection%20To%20The%20Server%20Was%20Unsuccessful%20-%20Android%202.2,%20jquerymobile,%200.9.5.1](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/7943)

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is for java based code. However OP is for **javascript/jquery** and **phonegap**. The following has helped me solve the issue.

In **config.xml**, add :

```
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="25000" /> 
<!-- Increase the value until the error is solved-->
```

The REAL problem here is that PhoneGap has an initial page load timeout of 20 seconds. If your page takes more than that ammount of time, you get this message.

```
Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful.   
(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
```